# What does the 'sq' mean in this sql statement?

Tags: sql, select

I read one SQL statement like this:

```
select top 1 id from (
  select top 1 id from sysobjects where xtype='u' order by id
) sq order by id desc
```

I don't understand what 'sq' in the last line stands for. Thanks for any helpful answers.s

Comment: It's an **alias** for the subquery, so you could potentially refer to individual columns of the subquery in your outer query

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this statement require that the result of the subquery must contain a column named id or must be only one column named id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an Alias for the subquery, it could also be written as: AS sq ...

```
select top 1 id from (
  select top 1 id from sysobjects where xtype='u' order by id
) AS sq order by id desc
```

Comment: If use AS, I can use any alias to replace sq, right?

Comment: Yes, but the use of "AS" word is optional, but it might be a cleaner way to refer it is just an Alias.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using the `sq` alias:

```
select top 1 sq.id from (
  select top 1 id from sysobjects where xtype='u' order by id
) sq order by id desc
```

You can have as many columns as you want in the subselect but there must be one called id. Here I am also aliasing the column names (since they are just constants in this case)

```
select top 1 sq.id from (
  select top 1 id, 'A' Col1, 'B' Col2, 7 as Col3 
  from sysobjects where xtype='u' order by id
) sq order by id desc
```